# onload form name is not defined, but it is?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Please forgive me for posting an image rather than code, but I thought it was necessary.

I'm sure it must be something simple. As you can see I have list defined, but I'm getting an error. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code of your `loadfrm()` and `ShowDefaultAttachmentRow()` functions. The error is saying that the variable you have which contains the `list` form isn't defined, not that the form doesn't exist.

Comment: I've removed `ShowDefaultAttachmentRow` and all the code from `loadfrm` and it makes no difference. `function loadfrm(frm, message_type) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `list` with `document.list` in your onload call like this:

```
<body onload="loadfrm(document.list, <%= 999 %>; ...">
...
```

Comment: Use `document.forms['list']`, because document.elementName isn't standards compliant and won't work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

From the little bit of visible code I'd say the problem is that you don't have a variable called `list`. Perhaps you intended to pass in the name of the form as a string, so like this:

```
onload="loadfrm('list', <%= 999 %>); ..."
```

Or perhaps the function expects a reference to the form itself:

```
onload="loadfrm(document.getElementsByName('list')[0], <%= 999 %>; "
// assuming there is only one form with that name
```

(Of course we can only guess based on what we can see: if you show the definition of your `loadfrm()` function we could help further...)

Comment: list is the name of the form.